# Eclipse debugger shortcut for exiting a for/while loop?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, keyboard-shortcuts

Group,

Is there an Eclipse keyboard shortcut key to exit a for/while loop while debugging?

Thanks,
Ranjit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a keyboard shortcut to exit a for/while loop, but you can move your cursor to the next statement after the for/while loop and use the "Run To Line" shortcut `Ctrl+R`

Answer (score 2):

Pressing `ctrl+R` is the correct option but if your break point is on a line which is inside the for loop, then you will have to first remove the break point and then press `ctrl+R` on the line on which you want the control to land. I faced this issue while debugging.